# Azure Kubernetes Service - az aks update

Tags: azure, azure-aks

What exactly does `az aks update --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <aks-cluster-name>` command do ?
Note: none of the optional arguments are supplied.

It asks for a reconciliation y/N option too after executing the command.

The documentation states this  -
*Update a managed Kubernetes cluster. When called with no optional arguments this attempts to move the cluster to its goal state without changing the current cluster configuration. This can be used to move out of a non succeeded state.*

What is the elaboration of the above?

Answer (score 0):

It works like any infrastructure as code apply works. It compares the desired state specified in the configuration with the current state of your AKS cluster. It determines what changes need to be made to bring the infrastructure to the desired state(Running/Succeeded).

It is very helpful when users apply unknown/unsupported changes in the MC_ resource group (infra rg of the cluster), or if a user wants to troubleshoot some issue.

For example, if a user deleted the VMSS directly (not by deleting a nodepool), if the above command is ran, the VMSS will be recreated.

P.S. its great if the cluster is facing an easy issue, it might not be helpful for some complicated problems.